# Как остановить процесс, запущенный через system()?

Tags: c++, linux

Допустим я ввел какую-нибудь команду, банально ping

```
system("ping www.google.com");
```

Как можно ее остановить, то-есть вызвать `^C` (Нажатие <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>)

Comment: Либо эмулировать нажатие клавиши через winAPI. Либо после запуска, находишь hWND окна и передаешь туда команды. Если в Linux через kill -STOP?

Comment: @MatthewBenjamin А как в линуксе тогда нужный PID данного процесса, чтобы его убить?

Comment: ps -axu | grep "название программы"

Comment: именно для вызова `system("<cmd>")` очень костыльные решения, через поиск PID вызовом `ps` и последующим `kill -s SIGINT <PID>`. Рекомендую использовать fork() + exec() в дочернем процессе - fork вернет PID дочернего процесса, с помощью которого можно послать сигнал потомку с помощью функции `int kill(pid_t pid, int sig);`

Comment: Не надо так делать. Используйте обычный shell.

Answer (score 0):

Из самой програмы, никак, вызов `system("ping google.com")` блокируется.

Надо вызывать через `fork()` + `exec()`. Тогда в запускающем процессе `fork()` вернет PID дочернего процесса. Передав его как параметр можно послать `TERM` сигнал дочернему процессу с помощью функции `int kill(pid_t pid, int sig)`.